# AWS API gateway - POST method response error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, response, aws-api-gateway

I am working on an image processing api. In the process, an image(.jpeg) of a screen is captured and via api-gateway POST'ed to lambda, from there its uploaded to s3 and then retrieved to process and extract text using open-cv. The extracted text to be returned via API-gateway as response.

I set the request parameters based on link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/

Since this is not a lambda-proxy, the settings for the integration response and the code is as done as in one of the answers to similar query: https://kennbrodhagen.net/2016/01/31/how-to-return-html-from-aws-api-gateway-lambda/

I have checked the cloud watch, and the entire code runs right. That is the image is saved, processed and the right text is extracted from the image. Yet response is "Internal server error".

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ......
    value = {'camera': 'image', 'image_name': 'cropped_frame0.jpeg', 'bpm': '117', 
             'spo2': '97'}

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        'body': json.dumps(value)
    }
```

curl --request POST -H "Accept: image/jpeg" -H "Content-Type: image/jpeg" --data-binary "@cropped_frame0.jpeg" https://XXXXX.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod

When i post the function using above curl i get {"message":"Internal Server Error"}

I am expecting the "value" as output (as in the code), because i will need this json output to be loaded to another api.

[This image is the cloud watch log for the lambda invocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFc9R.png)

[this is the Integration response set for API gateway. I have tried with empty mapping template as well for application/json. No luck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U94ry.png)

[this is the method response. maintained application/json empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53NZr.png)

Comment: What errors do you see in CloudWatch for the Lambda invocation?

Comment: As you're not using the Lambda proxy integration, have you set up an integration response in API Gateway as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html? You could also enable logging on API Gateway to check if you see something in the logs there. It'd also help if you could post your API Gateway configuration in the question as well.

Comment: @AnonCoward there are no errors in cloudWatch for lambda invocation as shown

Comment: @Dunedan I have updated the question with the screenshots of api gateway configuration. Can you please help me to understand your suggestion?